# Tuning Resonant Cavities

Tags: frequency, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, microwave, resonance

I have seen that some resonant cavities are equipped with some external screws, called tuners, which can be used to vary the resonance frequency.

Can you explain me the physical reason with which to screw or unscrew the tuner influences the electromagnetic field and the resonance frequency of the guide?

Comment: Just basic waveguide stuff. Back in the day, folks would stick their hand in front of a radar antenna dish, while someone else would "tweak" the waveguide. When it was just right, the person's hand would "get hot" and they'd know it was working right. Perhaps have a look at this [waveguide 101 article](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/waveguide-primer).

Comment: Tuning screws are typically used to adjust the cavity capacitance. They can also be used to introduce perturbations to cavities to cause multiple resonances or split modes, or to lower the cavity quality factor to broaden the resonant response. You would have to show the specific cavity and location of the tuning mechanism for a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

For us folks who've migrated from lower-frequency discrete LC resonators toward higher-frequency cavity resonator, the progression might be viewed this way:

[image: progress from discrete LC resonator to cavity resonator]
The cavity might be viewed as a hollow cylinder (like a tin can) with a central post electrically attached to the base, and extending up *almost* to the can's lid. The small space between the top of the post and can lid is the capacitor, whose spacing can be tuned with a screw.

Alternative views:
A coaxial transmission line is shorted at **one end**. It is less than one-quarter wavelength long. At the open end, a discrete capacitor is added to tune to resonance.

A coaxial transmission line is shorted at **both ends**. It is less than one-half wavelength long. At the mid-point a capacitor is added to tune to resonance.